# Python C Extensions - Why must callable C functions take arguments and return PyObject *

Tags: python, c, python-c-extension

I'm just starting to play with Python C extensions and am curious as to why a C function, which is callable from Python must take 2 PyObject* arguments and return a PyObject*. I wrote the following "Hello World" extension:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
hello_world(PyObject *self, PyObject *noargs)
{
   printf("Hello World\n");
   return Py_BuildValue("");
}


// Module functions table.

static PyMethodDef
module_functions[] = {
    { "hello_world", hello_world, METH_NOARGS, "hello world method" },
    { NULL }
};


// This function is called to initialize the module.
PyMODINIT_FUNC
inittesty2(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("testy2", module_functions);
}
```

Why can't I (especially with METH_NOARGS) use the following hello_world method:

```
static void
hello_world()
{
   printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several things to say about the various `PyObject` pointers.

1. The one required as **return type** is used for the **exception handling mechanism.** Specifically, if your function returns a null pointer, the Python interpreter will throw an exception. (You should only do that after calling one of the `PyErr_..` functions to set a specific exception.)

   This also means that whenever you do not want to throw an exception, you **must return a pointer to some real `PyObject`.** If there is nothing in particular your function is supposed to return, simply return `Py_None` (best use the `Py_RETURN_NONE` macro to get the reference count right), or "true" (using `Py_RETURN_TRUE`).
2. The **first argument**, `PyObject *self` points to the object the function is called from, or to the module instance it belongs to. Note that **every function you define is either a class method, or a module method.** There are no totally independent functions.
3. The **second** argument, `PyObject *args` points to the function argument (which may be a tuple or list of multiple arguments). You are right in pointing out that a function that does not take any arguments should not need this — and, as far as I can tell, you are right. You do not have to define it; you can simply define a function as

   ```
   static PyObject *PyMyClass_MyFunc(PyObject *self) {
     /* ..do something.. */
     Py_RETURN_TRUE;
   }
   ```

   You will still have to **cast this to `PyCFunction`** when you put it into the `PyMethodDef` for the data type you define, but I believe that cast is safe as long as you use the `METH_NOARGS` flag. **But note the comments below for possible risks.**
4. Finally, a function may in fact have a **third argument** like this:

   ```
   static PyObject *PyMyClass_Func(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
   {
     /*...*/
   }
   ```

   The third argument is used for *named, optional* arguments. In this case, too, you must **cast the function pointer to `PyCFunction`**, but that, too, is safe if you set the right flag (`METH_KEYWORDS`) for your function in the method table.

Comment: It's `Py_None`, not `PyNone`. Also there's `Py_RETURN_NONE` similar to `Py_RETURN_TRUE` and `Py_RETURN_FALSE`.

Comment: For (3), correct me if I'm wrong but if the code was using a calling convention where all args are passed on the stack and the callee (the function) pops them off the stack, removing the unused argument would cause a crash because Python will always pass NULL as the second arg and the function would not pop it.

Comment: Yes, that's because in `cdecl` which you're probably using, args are pushed right-to-left onto the stack and are poped by caller. So the extra `NULL` on the stack will be ignored by the function. That doesn't mean it will work on any other calling convention. For example it won't for `stdcall`. As long as portability is not an issue for OP, I guess this is OK. If it is, I wouldn't skip the args.

Comment: @yak Ok, thanks for pointing this out. There might indeed be a risk I wasn't aware of. I have edited the post; it takes your comments into account now.

Comment: For what it's worth, (3) worked when I tried it, but the compiler did give me the following warning - " warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]" when I tried to declare the 'arg-less' function in the module functions array

Answer (score 4):

The first argument for module level functions is the module object. When defining classes in C (the same `PyMethodDef` structure is used for methods there), the first argument is the instance (similar to `self` in Python).

When using `METH_NOARGS`, Python will pass `NULL` as the second argument. They could cast it to a function with one argument but I guess they didn't think it's needed.

The return value is easy to explain. Every Python function has a return value. If you don't explicitly use `return` in Python, the function will return `None`.

Of course in C you have to be explicit about the return value so if you don't use it, you have to return `None` yourself. Python provides a macro for this:

```
Py_RETURN_NONE;
```

Alternatively you could access the global `None` instance yourself:

```
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
return Py_None;
```

but the macro is easier to use.

You could think that returning `NULL` should be equivalent to `None` but `NULL` is used to indicate that the function raised an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Because Python functions, even trivial ones that just print to stdout, are more than just wrappers around C functions.

In the simplest case, think about the introspection facilities in Python. A Python function is a full-fledge object that you can query:

```
>>> def hello():
...     print 'hello'
... 
>>> dir(hello)
['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
```

You could of course imagine an extension facility that just wrapped C functions.
Check out [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html), which lets your write extensions for lots of scripting languages, including Python. Because it's going for the lowest common denominator, it'll let you wrap a function like your `hello_world`, but of course you lose a lot of power, too.